# Conformal functions and Schwartz's lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ and $H$ be the open unit disk and the open right plane respectively in $ \Bbb C$ and $F= \{f:D\to H\mid f(0)=1 \}$ where all $f\in F$ are holomorphic.

I need to find $\max\{|f(z)|: f\in F \}$ and $\min\{|f(z)|: f\in F \}$

Using $φ(z)= {z+1 \over 1-z}$ and Schwartz's lemma I managed to show that for every $f\in F$ we have

i) $f(D(0,r)) \subset φ(D(0,r))$ for every $r \in (0,1)$

ii) $|f'(0)| \le |φ'(0)|$

But I can't seem to make anything of it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the image $\varphi(D(0,r))$ is a disk in $H$ with its center on the real axis. Make a picture to conclude what this means for the maximum and minimum modulus in terms of $r$. Note that $\varphi$ itself shows that these bounds are sharp.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please give me some more details? So far I have only managed to see that $φ(D(0,1))$ is a disk. I'm having trouble with the other observations

Comment: Wat are the minimum and maximum moduli of points on that disk (i.e. in the image of $\varphi$)?

Comment: Is it ${1-r \over 1+r} \le |φ(z)| \le {r+1 \over 1-r}$ for $z \in D(0,r)$?

Comment: @Amontillado Yes.  :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I couldn't come back to it until now. But thanks, now I see it!